# Where is the API from the LSC Smart Connect app, for a project with a lamp?

Tags: python, smart-device

I want to make a project in Python so that my Wi-Fi bulb lights up the same color as the sky in real time.
I can't find the API from the app (LSC Smart Connect).

I have tried to find it on the website from them but there is nothing to find, just the products.
I asked some ki's too but they lead all to the same web site.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.